# How to calculate sha256 hash in Groovy 2.4

Tags: groovy, jmeter, sha256, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to calculate a sha256 hash in Groovy version 2.4.16. This is part of a jmeter test and that is the version of Groovy it supports, and I don't think I can change that. I'm aware that [in Groovy 2.5 you can use code like this](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2018/06/groovy-goodness-calculate-md5-and-sha.html):

```
def challenge = verifier.digest('SHA-256');
log.info 'challenge' + challenge
```

but this doesn't work/exist in 2.4. How can I do this in Groovy 2.4?

The error I get with the above code is:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.digest() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [SHA-256]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), next(), size(), toSet(), size(), toList()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:935) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:537) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DigestUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) class functions for encryption in general and in particular for your case it would be [DigestUtils.sha256Hex()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha256Hex-java.lang.String-)

The following statement:

```
vars.put('foo', org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex('bar'))
```

will store SHA-256 encoded hash of `bar` line into `foo` JMeter Variable, you will be able to access it as `${foo}` where required

`vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance and it provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables in current thread context. Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article to learn more about this and other JMeter API shorthands available for Groovy scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Use JMeter's function [digest](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) instead for SHA-256

> ```
> ${__digest(SHA-256,Felix qui potuit rerum cognoscere causas,mysalt,,)}
> ```
>
> digest function returns an encrypted value in the specific hash algorithm with the optional salt, upper case and variable name.

Example of usage in Parameters field and using output with `args[0]`
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! I was able to call it with `${__digest(SHA-256,verifier,'',false,challenge)};` after declaring challenge.

Comment: My syntax appears to be trying to set a property on the jmeter script itself, giving me this error msg:
Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler - groovy, message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ec2a0258be4f8cb338b740dea03abd0fbe09d4fecf102ae7a8f0e3c72b658f4f for class: Script40
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ec2a0258be4f8cb338b740dea03abd0fbe09d4fecf102ae7a8f0e3c72b658f4f for class: Script40

Comment: @ssmith use function outside JSR223 script

Comment: Yeah but I need it in the JSR223 script (I think). I can't figure out how to pass it in a variable (rather than literal string).

Comment: @ssmith use as args of JSR223

Comment: @ssmith added example of usage in Parameters field and using output with `args[0]`